# How to pass data from one flex application to another?

Tags: apache-flex

i have two flex applications and i want to pass the data from one application to another.Is there any way to do the same.Plz reply

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private var lc : LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
private var connectionString = mySWFLoader.content["connectionString"];
lc.send( connectionString, "thisIsMyMethod", "theseAreMyParameters" );
```

Edit: no need of JavaScript or 3rd party languages, just see the complete tutorial for communication between 2 flex applications [HERE](http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Local+Connections)

Comment: It works fine for firefox but  it gives error:
ArgumentError: Error #2082: Connect failed because the object is already connected.
 at flash.net::LocalConnection/connect()

Comment: Refer to my edit text with the link where you can see the full tutorial, this snippet may need little changes.

Comment: I got it working but it works only if both of the applications(swf) are running. but what i want is that only one will be running at starting and then on the basis of data clicked there the second will open with the data of the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can use JavaScript to communicate between the two Flex applications. See [this tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-javascript-tutorial-simple-interaction) for some examples.